# JS ES6/ES10 - conditionally change properties in an Array of Object by another Array of Object

Tags: javascript

I have a list of orders that I need to modify using another array of objects:

```
const orders = [
    {
        "shippingCost": 4.23,
        "orderStatus": "PAID",
        "sid": "2AB8FDC19B0E77F738171D8E396BCEE0",
        "creationDate": "2021-09-13T04:17:23",
        "orderId": "12-07303-03670",
        "itemCount": 2,
        "multiOrders": 2,
        "rowNumber": 1,
        "merged": 1
    },
    {
        "shippingCost": 4.29
        "orderStatus": "PAID",
        "sid": "2AB8FDC19B0E77F738171D8E396BCEE0",
        "creationDate": "2021-08-24T16:02:12",
        "orderId": "08-07513-82414",
        "itemCount": 2,
        "multiOrders": 2,
        "rowNumber": 2,
        "merged": 1
    },
    {
        "shippingCost": 6.22,
        "orderStatus": "PAID",
        "sid": "A63E0D42132D3245E8A3B0AAF00B6C3B",
        "creationDate": "2021-07-18T17:50:31",
        "orderId": "16-07301-37416",
        "itemCount": 4,
        "multiOrders": 4,
        "rowNumber": 1,
        "merged": 1
    }
];

const changed=[
    {
        "sid": "D2BD1A6E9DE4C81A3D58138FE35958A0",
        "orderId": "12-07303-03670",
    },
    {
        "sid": "7F9DF7D3D1735BB39CED4866E28FF9F1",
        "orderId": "16-07301-37416",
    }
];
```

I'm currently using this algorithm to change some values, but I'm (quite) sure there's a better way to do it: can pls suggest a better or more elegant method?

```
changed.forEach(i=> {
    let idx=orders.findIndex(o=>o.orderId==i.orderId)
    newData={"sid":i.sid,"rowNumber":1,"itemCount":1,"merged":0}
    Object.assign(this.orders[idx],newData)
    console.log(orders[idx])
})
```

thanks

Comment: Why do you change itemCount rowNumber and merged too? And what you do works I assume. You COULD map the main array and lookup the SID on the smaller array

Comment: Beside a missing check if `.findIndex()` has found something to modify this looks totally fine.

Comment: @mplungjan need to change `itemCount` and other properties 'cause the changed array is the response to unmerge action, therefore that values are fixed. But mapping (ie: using `Array.map`) return a new Array, while I wanna modify `orders` array

Comment: @Andreas well, yes, better to add a check.. although `changed` is the response of an ajax call where the `orderId` has been passed therefore `.findIndex` should always return a value

Comment: @Joe See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69943970/295783)

Comment: OK, thanks.. I thought was "better" using `assign` avoiding `item.` repetition. Thanks

Comment: @Joe Good idea. updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK; It does have to look up the orderId every time

If the input array is short or the changes are early in the original array then your code is faster than the example below - if not, not:

```js
const orders = [ { "shippingCost": 4.23, "orderStatus": "PAID", "sid": "2AB8FDC19B0E77F738171D8E396BCEE0", "creationDate": "2021-09-13T04:17:23", "orderId": "12-07303-03670", "itemCount": 2, "multiOrders": 2, "rowNumber": 1, "merged": 1 }, { "shippingCost": 4.29, "orderStatus": "PAID", "sid": "2AB8FDC19B0E77F738171D8E396BCEE0", "creationDate": "2021-08-24T16:02:12", "orderId": "08-07513-82414", "itemCount": 2, "multiOrders": 2, "rowNumber": 2, "merged": 1 }, { "shippingCost": 6.22, "orderStatus": "PAID", "sid": "A63E0D42132D3245E8A3B0AAF00B6C3B", "creationDate": "2021-07-18T17:50:31", "orderId": "16-07301-37416", "itemCount": 4, "multiOrders": 4, "rowNumber": 1, "merged": 1 } ]; const changed=[ { "sid": "D2BD1A6E9DE4C81A3D58138FE35958A0", "orderId": "12-07303-03670", }, { "sid": "7F9DF7D3D1735BB39CED4866E28FF9F1", "orderId": "16-07301-37416", } ];

orders.forEach(item => {
  const change = changed.find(change => item.orderId === change.orderId); 
  if (change)  Object.assign(item, { sid:change.sid, rowNumber : 1, itemCount : 1, merged : 0})
})
  

console.log(orders)
```